# Getting Error res.setHeader not a Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules

I am trying to create a nodejs server. I used **res.setHeader** method to set content-type as text/html. But after starting the server getting error that **res.setHeader** is not a function;
Following is my code:

```js
const http=require('http');

const server=http.createServer((res,req)=>{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html')
    res.write('<h1>Hello This is response from NodeJS>Server</h1>')

    res.end()
    
})


server.listen(8000);
```

[I have attached image that clearly shows that this is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2xvm.png)

Comment: change the order of params, (req,res).

Comment: Hello Akshay, After changing the order params it working fine. Thanks for helping Bro.

Answer (score 3):

`res` is the second argument, not the first argument.

```
const server=http.createServer((req, res)=>{
...
```

Here is the doc: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Hello Senta, After changing the order params it working fine. Thanks for helping Bro